# How to enable nuget on Artifactory without using Pro features?

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I just started using Artifactory for my pet project and I want to configure it to support nuget. I know that Artifactory Pro supports nuget but I am curious if it's possible to do that without using Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You might consider applying for an account in oss.jfrog.org (if your project is popular and open-source).

Comment: I am testing the Pro version now. I found another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420595/how-to-setup-virtual-repository-on-artifactory. :)