# How to setup virtual repository on Artifactory?

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I just started to use Artifactory Pro (trial) and I have a problem to set virtual repository. I added a new virtual repository which contains one local and one remote repositories. The problem is there is no item on the feed.

[Document on the website](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) does not help me either. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "no item on the feed"?

Comment: @JBaruch there is no item when I browse the virtual url using nuget explorer.

Comment: @Anonymous are you using the latest version of nuget explorer?

Comment: @Anonymous this seems to be working fine with the Nuget command line client, so it might be an issue with the Nuget explorer implementation

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that Nuget Explorer is the problem.

Using artifactory to aggregate feeds fails for me using Nuget Explorer, however
Visual Studio 2013 works.

Using ProGet to aggregate feeds works for me using Nuget Explorer, as well with Visual Studio 2013.

I would say this is an Artifactory problem.

Comment: Talked to JFrog, they can't repo this in 3.3.0, I was using 3.2.0.  Will update as I get more info.